# javascript addition result

Tags: javascript, math, console.log, calculation

The code below

Should get result = 8, But I get 9.

Should get result_2 = 9, But I get 8.

```js
let num_1 = 5;
let num_2 = 3;
let result = num_1 + num_2;
let result_2 = result++;

console.log(result);
console.log(result_2);
```

Comment: 5+3 is 8 and adding 1 to 8 which becomes 9... increment operator [++](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

Comment: Your expectations are not correct. Post-increment operator increases the value of its operand after the value is used in an expression.

Comment: `val++` = *return val, then add 1 to val*.   So result2 should by 8 and result should be 9.  Where's the issue?

Comment: If you want to "add 1 but not increment value" then use `result2 = result + 1` not `++`